# Firestore onSnapshot is firing for every element in a collection on a single deletion

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

**Edit**: I think this is a bug in RxFire. I tried to repro just on the Firebase SDK and it doesn't repro -- my duplicate logging confused me.

The AngularFire/RxFire code is:

```js
collectionChanges(collection(
    this.firestore, "collection1/doc1/collection2"))
.subscribe(changes => {
  console.log('AngularFire changes', changes);
});
```

This is what triggers 1 removal + unlimited edits. I'm guessing it's something in that. I'll file a GitHub issue there.

---

I have Firestore code similar to the following:

```js
const q = query(collection(this.firestore, "collection1/doc1/collection2"));

onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  const docs = snapshot.docChanges();
  console.log("Changes received", docs);
});
```

This generally works: When the page loads, I get `added` events for every document in the collection. When a document changes, a single `modified` event fires. However, when a document is deleted, the next change batch includes a `removed` event (good) and also a `modified` event for every other element in the collection (bad).

Any idea why these extra modify events are happening + how to avoid all the extra reads? or is this all from the cache?

I've verified there's no actual change to the other documents in the collection. A single modified change mentions oldIndex and newIndex so I wonder if it's maybe trying to update the index of every element, but there isn't a sort order so any index is undefined anyways.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/rxfire/issues/75